# how to pass JSON data though a foreach loop in php

Tags: arrays, xml, json, foreach

I would like the JSON data to go thought a foreach loop in php but every time I try to do it I get this error message:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted
>   to string

*PHP:*

```
<?php
  $xml_events = simplexml_load_file('xml_data/current_events.xml');

  $results = array();


  foreach ($xml_events->event as $event) {
    array_push($results, array(
        'name' => $event->name,
        'cover' => $event->cover,
    ));
  }

  $data = json_encode($results);
  $json = json_decode($data);

  foreach ($json as $name)
  {
    echo $name->name; 
  }
```

*XML:*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <event>
    <name>Barclays ATP World Tour Finals</name>
  </event>
</data>
```

*JSON Data:*

```
"[{"name":{"0":"Barclays ATP World Tour Finals"}},{"name":{"0":"2015 National Television Awards"}},{"name":{"0":"Barclays ATP World Tour Finals"}},{"name":{"0":"Barclays ATP World Tour Finals"}},{"name":{"0":"Barclays ATP World Tour Finals"}},{"name":{"0":"Doctor who"}},{"name":{"0":"Apple Party"}},{"name":{"0":"ice-cream"}}]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$name is an object, so the solution is to use:

```
echo $name->name->{0};
```